# refreshing gmail only one time per hour

Tags: email, redirect, gmail, webmail

I've a webmail in my own domain like eg office@mydomain.com, but that webmail is quite poor so I decided to migrate to gmail. I had created mail like mydomain@gmail.com and gave a redirection from my webmail to gmail. Everythin' is ok but....gmail is refreshed only one time per hour. My host provider said they push my e-mails immediately after receiving, but the problem is in gmail.

I found some info about option "refresh POP account" but - most likely - that option is no longer available in gmail labs.

Any idea, how to force gmail to refreshing at least every (few) minutes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "refresh POP account" has been integrated into gmail (http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.nl/2012/08/three-gmail-labs-graduation-into.html) so by using the "refresh" button pop servers should be refreshed.

However we have a problem that sometimes we know we have emails on our pop servers yet gmail writes it checked 0 minutes ago and didn't find any. Yet 30 mins later the mail gets retrieved so my conclusion is it doesn't always work.